# How to parallelized a for loop with GNU Parallel

Tags: bash, gnu-parallel

I want to parallelize a for loop using bash. My script is:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "START"
END=5000000
for i in $(seq 1 $END)
do
   j=i+5
done
echo "END"
```

And I'm trying to parallelize it using GNU parallel, as I said before, by running this code with the following command:

```
time parallel sh prueba1.sh
```

Now, I know this is wrong first because is not working and second because it's too simplistic...

How can I run it correctly in parallel?

PD: I've been following [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OpaiGYxkSuQ):

Comment: What is there to parallelize? It's just `j="i+5"`,  no matter how many times or how many threads you run.. For which arguments do you want the command to parallelize? Have you at least read the man page? Or do you just want `time parallel sh prueba1.sh -- 1 2`

Comment: Why try and run a `bash` script with `sh`? Why enumerate a list of 5 million numbers before you even get started, use `for ((i=0;i<5000000;i++))` instead.

Comment: Ok thank you.what I'm trying to do is to parallelized the sum, I mean, that is each core running a part of the sum. I'm just trying to grasp the idea.

Comment: @kamil cuk. What do you mean with that last sentence? What does it do?

Comment: Read [man parallel](https://linux.die.net/man/1/parallel). `parallel runs the specified command, passing it a single one of the specified arguments. This is repeated for each argument. Jobs may be run in parallel.` You need to pass arguments. As many as many jobs you want, if you want the jobs to be run in parallel. In the example I posted there are two arguments - `1` and `2`, and the script may be run parallel with each of the arguments.